# Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

Tags: angular, testing

I have issue with error from topic. I'm using angular 7 version.
There is my test: landing.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LandingComponent } from './landing.component';
import { PegasPanelComponent } from '../pegas-panel/pegas-panel.component';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateServiceStub } from 'src/app/app-tests.spec';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


describe('LandingComponent', () => {
  let component: LandingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LandingComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LandingComponent, PegasPanelComponent, ],
      imports: [RouterModule, TranslateModule],
      providers: [{
        provide: TranslateService,
        useClass: TranslateServiceStub
      }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LandingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

landing.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing',
  templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing.component.scss']
})
export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { translateService.setDefaultLang('en'); }

  public ngOnInit() { }
}
```

app-tests.spes.ts:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class TranslateServiceStub{

    public get(key: any): any {
        return of(key);
    }

  public setDefaultLang() {
    return of('en');
  }

    public onLangChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    public onTranslationChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); 
    public onDefaultLangChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

And error:

```
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) LandingComponent should create FAILED
        Failed: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
        Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
```

I don't have any ideas how to fix it. Trying to add routing and move translateModule from declarations to imports (two answers i found) but this doesn't help.

Comment: THUMB RULE : "Components are placed in a declaration array and modules are placed in import array."
-
While helping one of my friend, I found the same error in one of the spec.ts file. It happens because one Module is imported in declaration array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import path for the translate module stub is absolute rather than relative so I'd try changing that, depending on your build options this may be causing issues.

Additionally the import of `routes` seems wrong - usually you'd provide these as a parameter to the routing module, but for the unit test file you can probably just omit them

The router testing module should be imported like `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])` - see https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule

Comment: The path is not a issue here, i have similiar implementations in other components but only a few have this issue, not really sure why. At the next point i check your link and try to make something like that: imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
        routes
      ), ], but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

The `imports: [RoutingModule, routes]` is where your issue comes from. `routes` is assumed to be an `Object` (`Array`) of possible routes like the following:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

(taken from https://angular.io/guide/router)

This object is not meant to be passed as an import, but it rather should be used with the `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` or `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`, depending on your setup.

I think for your unit test, you can just leave the `routes` and `RouterTestingModule` out and see what that does. Unit tests shouldn't be too interested in all routing, unless the component specifically is in charge of routing and you want to test that.

If that's the case, it'll throw errors saying things like "Could not find provider" etc.

Comment: As you can see i don't have any tests of routing inside (and i not have plans for implement it there). So, i decided to try delete this for a while and ... same error. Nothin changes. Looks it's unecessary there. I editing a main post for give you more clear view.

Comment: `TranslateModule` cannot be imported as a `declaration`, just remove it in totality. If any of the tests or the component being setup requires it; it'll whine about it and you can add it back as an `imports: []`, because it's a module.

If that doesn't change anything, I'm pretty certain it's in your `TranslateServiceStub`, either in the way it's imported or the way it is made and exported.

Comment: I try this and i meeting another blocking me error: TypeError: translateService.setDefaultLang is not a function. If i pass one of them - i think im in home

Comment: That's cause it requires the TranslateService, so you can add to `imports: []` the `TranslateModule`, although I'm sure it has a `Testing` variant, so I'd suggest you import that and see what happens next.

Comment: Which error? The `is not a function` or the `[Object object]` error? If it's the Object error, could you please show your `TranslateServiceStub` file?
Also, is that `..., ]` in your actual code at the `declarations` part? It seems like that's not supposed to be there.

Comment: TypeError: translateService.setDefaultLang is not a function. - sorry for missleading. I posted stub it in the first, main post in this topic, you can chceck it easy.

Comment: Alright, well if you take a look at your stub and the error message. The error says "setDefaultLang" is not a function, and in your stub you indeed do not have a `setDefaultLang` function. Your stub is incomplete. I would recommend you Google around for other examples on how to stub the TranslateService.
(https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/636)

You also could consider not providing the TranslateService and just properly importing the TranslateModule; this will automatically add the service for you.

Comment: I added some code to my stub and now i have problem with routerOutler (what a mess): Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[RouterOutlet -> ChildrenOutletContexts]:
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterOutlet -> ChildrenOutletContexts]:
            NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!. I edited a code what i did in first post.

Comment: Ok, i did it, i was eally tired of this and i missed i put to import RouterModule, not RouterTestingModule. Now i have -1 test on my way. Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to hear that! Good luck with the rest! Don't forget to mark or upvote the comments or answers that helped you solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also experience this problem if you have imported a provider in your list of imports instead of putting it in your list of providers.

That potential mistake is worth checking if none of the answers seems to be working for you.

Answer (score 0):

If i moving TranslateModule.forRoot() from declarations to imports i had error with RouterModule. I fixed it fast but i meet another blocking error (error because of i moved TranslateModule.forRoot() to declarations): 
TypeError: translateService.setDefaultLang is not a function - i using newest versions of angula and translator.

Example new code: landing.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LandingComponent } from './landing.component';
import { PegasPanelComponent } from '../pegas-panel/pegas-panel.component';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateServiceStub } from 'src/app/app-tests.spec';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


describe('LandingComponent', () => {
  let component: LandingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LandingComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LandingComponent, PegasPanelComponent, ],
      imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot(), RouterModule],
      providers: [{
        provide: TranslateService,
        useClass: TranslateServiceStub
      }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LandingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```